# Unexpected end of input - beginner js

Tags: javascript

Hey I just started learning js today. I'm trying to write a basic 'fizzbuzz' program that goes up to a certain number inputted by the user. However, the final squiggly bracket of the 'for loop' is not working. It it just wrong syntax or is it an issue with js?

```
function fizzbuzz(num) {
    if (num % 15 == 0) {
        return "fizzbuzz";
    } else {
        if (num % 3 == 0) {
            return "fizz";
        } else {
            if (num % 5 == 0) {
                return "buzz";
            } else {
                return num;
            }
        }
    }

let answer = parseInt(prompt("Please enter the number you would like to fizzbuzz up to: "));

for (let i = 1; i <= answer; i++) {
    console.log(fizzbuzz(i))
}
```

I've tried reformatting the 'for loop' as well as putting a semi-colon at the end of the console.log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close the function with a squiggly bracket

```js
function fizzbuzz(num) {
  if (num % 15 === 0) {
    return "fizzbuzz";
  } else {
    if (num % 3 === 0) {
      return "fizz";
    } else {
      if (num % 5 === 0) {
        return "buzz";
      } else {
        return num;
      }
    }
  }
}

let answer = parseInt(prompt("Please enter the number you would like to fizzbuzz up to: "));

for (let i = 1; i <= answer; i++) {
  console.log(fizzbuzz(i))
}
```